# How to open a CSV-fil with PHP and fopen

Tags: php, fopen

Using different snippets of code I've found around the internet, I've put together this code:

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="csv" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$file = fopen($csv, 'r');
  echo "<table>" ;
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo $line[0];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $line[2];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $line[5] * 1000;
  echo "</td></tr>";


}
fclose($file) . " ";

echo "</table>";

?>
```

This doesn't work, but if I replace

```
fopen('MatchResults-12789503873441817.csv'
```

with

```
fopen('<name of ulpaded file>.csv'
```

it works well.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Edit:
Changed

```
$file = fopen('csv', 'r');
```

to

```
$file = fopen($csv, 'r');
```

Comment: That's the way `fopen()` works. You have to provide a filename; `fopen('csv', 'r');` points to a file called 'csv', which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: You probably want something like this: `fopen( $_FILES['csv']['name'] , 'r');`  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Sorry, I ment to have $csv instead of 'csv'. Edited the original post.

Comment: Still, `$csv` is undefined in your code.  You need to set it from the $_FILES or the $_POST superglobal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use method of `post` as in

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
// -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Data will be sent to the PHP script in an array called `$_POST`

If the input field is called `csv` as in

```
<input type="text" name="csv" value="" />
// ----------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then there should be an occurance in `$_POST` called `csv`

```
$file = fopen($_POST['csv'], 'r');
```

although you should check that the data was actually sent before using it

```
if ( isset($_POST['csv'] ) {

    $file = fopen($_POST['csv'], 'r');

    // other code

}
```

Comment: You are 100% right. This worked perfectly! Thanks :)